# windows phone 8 resource path at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I have to include some files with my windows phone 8 app. the app will accordingly get those file from resource and read or show partly the content according to the algorithm. how do i get the path to my embedded resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include file in you project, for instance in Data folder of your project (in our case json file) as a resource then use next code to get content from that file:

```
string content = string.Empty;
string resource_file = "Data/myfile.json";

if (IsLocalResourceFileExists(resource_file))
        {
            var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/YourProjectName;component/" + resource_file, UriKind.Relative));
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
        }
```

To check if file exist in resource use this:

```
public bool IsLocalResourceFileExists(string relativePath)
    {
        return Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/YourProjectName;component/" + relativePath, UriKind.Relative)) != null;
    }
```

Change YourProjectName to name of you project.
After this, conten holds json file as string.

Hope this help

Comment: Note that resource are loaded at app startup, if you load big files as resources this will cause a delay on startup. You can prefer content type instead.

Comment: i have C library which will dynamically read the some files according to the algorithm. so the library needs the path to files only. so i think creating the Uri is enough?

Comment: Set the build action of the file as Content (click on the file and press F4 for properties) and access the file with a Uri.