# Wp8 cant find csv file in project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, path, stream, directory

I'm using the MVVM structure and I wish to read a csv file, which I've added in the same folder as the viewmodel. I've tried to use the second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531968/how-to-read-files-from-project-folders) question, but my variable var is null, so it doesn't seem to find the file. Beneath is an image of the folders and what I've done so far.

[image]

Can anyone help me get the destination of the file so I can use it as a stream?

Comment: are you sure that your MapToUse variable has the value in it? Did you check that?

Comment: Can you check the *BuildAction* of the file?

Comment: @KasunKodagoda I checked the name of MapToUse and it is the same as the filename, without the .csv ending

Comment: @Romasz You meen when I build the solution?

Comment: When you right clck on the file, choose properties and there you should find *Build Action* - check if it's set to *Content*, if it's *none*, then your file won't be included in the package.

Comment: @Romasz Oh, I already did that and, unfortunately it does not help

Comment: I'm not sure, but from the picture I can see that your map is in folder and your `destination` is just a map name. [Relative URI is relative to package, not a position of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394894/2681948). Have you tried providing URI's path like this: `"/StartUpViewModels/" +  destination`? Also providing [such path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100886/2681948) may help.

Comment: @Romasz I just tried adding the paths as you set, but with no luck. any other suggestions?

Comment: @JonasN89 Is it possible that you can share a working project with an issue?

Comment: @Romasz I got it working by using @"StartUpViewModels/" + destination, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: Yeah, that slash `/` shouldn't be at the first place.

Comment: @Romasz Yeah, If you add it as an answer, I'll give it to you as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a path relative to your package, thus it should work if done like this:

```cs
var dest = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"StartUpViewModels/" + destination, UriKind.Relative));
```

[Here is also reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394894/2681948) to answer to similar question.

Remember also to check if your resource file added to package has *Build Action* set to *Content*, otherwise if it's set to *None*, your file won't be added.